# Let $G$ be a group and $a,b \in G$ show that $|b| = 5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that if $|a|=2$, $ab^2a^{-1}=b^3$ and $b\ne e$, then $|b|=5$.

My attempt

$$a^2 = e \implies a * a = e \implies a = a^{-1}$$
$$ab^2a=b^3$$
$$(ab^2a)^2=(b^3)^2$$
**I)** $$ab^2aab^2a = b^5$$
$$ab^2a=b^3$$
$$ab^2ab^2=b^3b^2$$

**II)** $$ab^2ab^2 = b^5$$

**I** and **II**$\implies$$b^4 = b^5 \implies b = e \implies b^5 = e$

Of course it is wrong, I've been trying to solve this problem for over 2 hours but I can't find a way to show $b^5=e$ through the given properties.

Comment: If $b=e$ then $ab^2a^{-1}=b^3$.

Comment: A reminder: $|b|=5$ certainly means that $b^5=e$, but $b^5=e$ does not mean $|b|=5$. The exception (in fact, the only exception) is $b=e$.

Comment: One potential source of error from your work: $$(b^3)^2 = (b^3)(b^3) = b^6$$ as opposed to $b^5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ab^2a^{-1}=ab^2a=b^3$$
$$ab^2a^{-1}ab^2a=ab^4a=b^6=a((ab^2a)b)a=b^2aba$$
$$b^6=b^2aba\implies b^4=aba$$
$$ab^4a=a(aba)a=b^6\implies b=b^6$$
$$b^5=e$$

Comment: Why  $ab^4a = b^6$ ?

Comment: @hjx In the third line I show $b^4=aba$; then I substitute $b^4$ in $ab^4a$ with $aba, then simplify.

Comment: $b^6= (b^3)^2 = (ab^2a^{-1})(ab^2a)= ab^4a$

Answer (score 3):

From the given $$b^{-2}ab^2=ba,$$ which gives
$$(ba)^2=e$$ or
$$ab=b^{-1}a.$$

In another hand, 
$$ab=b^3ab^{-1}.$$
Thus, $$e=baba=b(b^3ab^{-1})a=b^4ab^{-1}a=b^4a(ab)=b^5$$
and we are done!

Answer (score 2):

One has

$ab^2 = b^3a$, then $(ab^2)^2 = b^3ab^3a = b^3a(ab^3a)ba = b^6aba$

$b^5 = b^3b^2 = ab^2a^{-1}b^2=ab^2ab^2=(ab^2)^2 = b^6aba$.

So, $baba = e$, then $b^{-1} = aba$, or $b^{-2} = ab^2a = b^3$, then $b^5=e$.